# How can I list numbers?

Tags: php, for-loop, numbers, echo

```
     <?
   $numbers = "numbers+";
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
        $numbers .= $i.',';
        echo $numbers."<br>";
        } 
    ?>
```

My code snippet here is. Now I wanna that when $i variable be last number on each line, (,) don't appear after $i. Output I want :

```
numbers+1
numbers+1,2
numbers+1,2,3
numbers+1,2,3,4
numbers+1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $numbers = "numbers+";
 for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
      $numbers .= ($i>1 ? ',' : '').$i;
      echo $numbers."<br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
<?php
    $numbers = "numbers+";
    $tmp = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $tmp[] = $i;
        echo $numbers . implode(',', $tmp) . '<br/>';
    } 
?>
```

Also remember to use `<?php` instead of `<?` which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution with [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$numbers .= $i.',';
echo rtrim( $numbers, ',' )."<br>";
```

Or simply add the comma only after you've printed the value.

```
$numbers .= $i;
echo $numbers."<br>";
$numbers .= ',';
```